# Protocol Inheritance in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, protocols

I am following [this](http://pawanpoudel.svbtle.com/test-driven-development-in-swift) tutorial to perform TDD in swift.

About halfway down, there is a point where we need to create a protocol that inherits from UITableViewController. Code looks like the following:

```
import UIKit

protocol MenuTableDataSource : UITableViewDataSource {
    func setMenuItems(menuItems: [MenuItem])
}
```

We then create a class shortly after, that conforms to MenuTableDataSource with the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MenuTableDefaultDataSource : NSObject, MenuTableDataSource {
var menuItems: [MenuItem]?

func setMenuItems(menuItems: [MenuItem]) {
    self.menuItems = menuItems
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
               -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
               -> UITableViewCell!
{
    return nil;
}
}
```

However, I still get an error saying Type 'MenuTableDefaultDataSource' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'.

I have also tried removing the optionals in the parameters numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath but the error still persists.

Where do I seem to be going wrong? Looking at the final source code given by the author, the same error also exists, which makes me think Apple may have changed something in the syntax that we are not aware of.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs have changed a lot since that tutorial was written in September 2014.

Take a look at the API reference for `UITableViewDataSource` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)

Namely, the main functions you are using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

These no longer rely on unwrapped optionals being passed in (there is no `!` attached)

Swift is brand new, and the APIs went through a lot of changes between June and November-ish, so if you are reading materials online, it is always a good idea to check the official docs online. (Even the official Xcode releases and the betas can have differing APIs sometimes)

Comment: Yep, as mentioned in the OP, I have tried removing the ! in the parameters and the problem still persists. 
Interestingly, when I start typing 'tableView', the code completion suggestions shows only SOME of the methods from UITableViewDataSource such as titleForFooterInSection and titleForHeaderInSection. However, the methods I am looking for, namely, cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection are not shown by the code completion (even with the current implementations of these methods being commente out first). I am perplexed as to why this happens?

Comment: I just put [this](http://pastebin.com/an6N0svT) into a storyboard, and the compiler didn't complain about a thing (Xcode 6.2 (6C107a)). (Thats not how you return `UITableViewCells`, but you are required to return something)

Comment: Ok after looking at your code, I removed all optionals in the method signatures and in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I returned UITableViewCell() just like you did rather than nil. This seemed to solved the problem. Thank you very much!